# WCF Best Practice/Cleanest Method implementation in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122

After Watching the Above video "Extreme WCF", I like the clean approach taken towards the layout of code.

However this does not directly apply to Silverlight.

I was wondering if either anyone knew how to tie the proxy at the end of the video into Silverlight, or if anyone knew of a similar method tidying WCF up.

Either that or a discussion on WCF techniques would be very helpful.

Thanks

```
  public class Proxy : ClientBase<ITaskAuditService> , ITaskAuditService
{
    #region ITaskAuditService Members

    public IEnumerable<TaskAuditType> GetList( string measure, string userName, string taskReason )
    {
        return Channel.GetList(measure, userName, taskReason);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()
    {
        return Channel.GetUsers();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetTaskReasons()
    {
        return Channel.GetTaskReasons();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetMeaures()
    {
        return Channel.GetMeaures();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

as requested the code is here i'm just missing the method of getting this into a silverlight project (and making it asyncrhonus)

Comment: If you want some feedback on a particular piece of code (e.g. "how to tie the proxy"), you might want to quote the code here.   That way we don't have to wade through the entire video just to help you with the small piece you're looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the best pratice, you may want to take a look at this book

> Programming WCF Services from Juval Löwy

It's the best book I found on the subject and it have a Chapter on "WCF Coding Standard"

I can't copy paste the entire chapter but you should be able the find it somewhere on the internet.

By the way, it's a good reference if you think using WCF for a while...